# B-button not rendering in VueJS with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

how are you guys doing?

I got stuck in a problem that i can't understand e obviously, couldn't solve.
I have a b-table and in the last column in this table, i have a b-button inside a template that should (theoretically) render.
The problem is, it was working normally before, now, in the test environment it doesn't render and in the production environment works normally.
I've tried to update the boostrapVue, make all the imports again, doing all of this for the entire application because it is happening in the entire application.
Also, drop the entire application out and clone the repo all over again, the same that is in production and the error is the same.
Here's the part of the code that is not rendering:

```
<template slot="actions" slot-scope="data">
            <b-button variant="info" v-b-modal.cadastroManutencaoDash @click="dashLineId(data.item)" class="mr-2">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Cadastrar Manutenção
            </b-button>
        </template>
```

The template tag comes normally but the b-button doesn't.

What could it be?

Can someone please help me?
Honestly, i'm not understanding what can be wrong.
I couldn't find anything that helped me in anywhere.
I know that it doesn't have to much code in this question but i think that is more global than local, anyway, if you guys need some more code just tell and i update the question.
Sorry for not passing the repo link but, is private from the company that i work and i don't think is a good idea.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using the old slot naming which was changed in the `2.0.0` release.

The following is using the new naming `cell({field})` and the new `v-slot` syntax, as the old one has been deprecated

```html
<template v-slot:cell(actions)="data">
  <b-button variant="info" v-b-modal.cadastroManutencaoDash @click="dashLineId(data.item)" class="mr-2">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Cadastrar Manutenção
  </b-button>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hiws, it's working perfectly. I didn't knew about this changes. I've looked at the docs but i think that i miss this. Thanks again.

Comment: @GabrielSassaki Take a look at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/misc/changelog#v200 to make sure you migrate everything properly

Comment: Thanks for your help @Hiws, i'll take a look at the docs, you're the master.

Answer (score 0):

i just downgrade my bootstrap-vue and it works.

It was in 2.0.3 and downgrade to 2.0.0-rc.26.